# Elegant way to check if a float is between two numbers in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, numbers, logic

How do I check if x is between a and b?

```
a = 9
b = 7
x = 7.5
```

I came up with this:

```
a < x < b or b < x < a
```

It seems to do the job from a few tests I made, but it looks unreadable and confusing. Any other better way?

Comment: Why is that unreliable or confusing, Seems perfectly clear to me.

Comment: better than `min(a, b) < x < max(a, b)`

Comment: Somewhat relevant: how are `a` and `b` getting set that you don't already know which of `a <= b` or `b <= a` is true?

Comment: you could figure out the bounds before the check but what do you class as "*better*"?

Comment: Redundant parentheses will go a long way to improving readability: `(a < x < b) or (b < x < a)`.

Comment: `(x < a) != (x < b)` would almost work, but it allows `x` to equal the lesser endpoint.

Answer (score 8):

What about using:

```
min(a, b) < x < max(a, b)
```

Answer (score 6):

came up with these four:

```
min(a, b) < x < max(a, b)

a < x < b if a < b else b < x < a

(a - x) * (b - x) < 0

not (b < x > a and a < x > b)
```

but still think your version is the best.

Comment: The first has two (relatively) expensive function calls, the multiplication may be wrong  if `x` is too close to `a` or `b`.

Comment: @chepner: What makes you think that `min` and `max` are expensive?!

Comment: Because the mere act of calling a function is relatively expensive in Python. It's not specific to `min` or `max`.

Comment: @chepner: The workings of Python are above my pay grade; I defer to your knowledge on that.

Comment: you are right, just list the solution come to my mind@Bathsheba

Comment: you mind me, I have made some experiments about `min/max` before in LeetCode, by compared with `if`,  it is not expensive than I thought @chepner

Comment: I would go with the first one even if it is a bit more expensive it is much more readable

Comment: Following some more thought, I'm inclined to agree with @recnac on this one.

Comment: The multiplication is not the problem; I'm just not confident that `x > a` implies that `x - a > 0`. I could be wrong, but it really doesn't seem worth the risk compared to just making a direct comparison.

Comment: agree with you, trade maybe a little bit performance for readability and usability @MitchelPaulin

Comment: @chepner: The wrangle I'm having is the case where the product of the differences is a subnormal value. But yes, too complex, just keep it as the OP has it.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah, that's probably a bigger problem than I was imagining. I don't deal a lot with floating-point values, but in general introducing arithmetic to an inherently non-arithmetic problem just seems to be asking for odd corner cases to introduce errors.

Comment: @chepner: Ensuring `x > a` implies `x-a > 0` is the reason subnormals exist.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be what you need. My other answer is nonsense and I wrote it too fast.

```
def is_between(a, x, b):
    return min(a, b) < x < max(a, b)
```

Take into account a and b should never be None. They should be both valid numbers

Comment: If you are going to wrap the comparison in a function, there's little reason to introduce two additional function calls.

Comment: You also cannot have spaces in the function name and it doesn't make sense to pass in a and b without x

Comment: @Sayse You are right. I edited.